# ios auto-layout: Programmatically set width constraint

Tags: iphone, ios, constraints, autolayout

I am working on an ios application. I am adding the auto-layout programmatically to 2 labels.

I need to add a constraint to make them equal width.

I know how to fix the width of a label by using :

```
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:myLabel
             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem: nil
           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
          multiplier:1.0f
            constant:200.0f];
```

That would fix the label size to a constant. But I have 2 labels and I want them to have equal size without having to set a constant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turned out I just have to do the following:

```
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:myLabel
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem: otherLabel
       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
      multiplier:1.0f
        constant:0];
```

Comment: why do you need a toItem: otherLabel?

Comment: the idea is to make the "myLabel" and "otherLabel" equal width. so I put one of them in the "withItem" and the other in the "otherItem"

Comment: what if I just want to add a width constrains to myLabel only? what would I put for "toItem". I tried nil but that doesn't do much. Thanks

Comment: @VanDuTran you have to put the `toItem: nil` and specify the wanted size in the constant. example `constant: 100` . if you are having problems you can post a new SO question and you will get answers for it.