# making UILabels / UITextFields looks the same proportionally on all phones

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Using autolayout, what is the best way to make something like this look the same on all iPhone sizes?

[image]

Adding constraints to all of the individual components has caused one of the UITextFields to be bigger than the rest every time, and I'm unsure how I could make them all look the same size, and fit proportionally on all iPhones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constraint that can establish a relationship of the with between two UIViews.

If you ctrl drag from Hours to Mins you can select "Width". Be sure that the constant value is 1. Then you can do the same from Hours to Seconds.

You can [also do it by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317495/ios-auto-layout-programatically-set-width-constraint) :

```
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myLabel
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:otherLabel
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                           constant:0];
```